# Apache Spark upgrade from 1.5.2 to 1.6.0 using homebrew leading to permission denied error during execution

Tags: linux, apache-spark, homebrew

I just upgraded Spark from 1.5.2 to 1.6.0 using Homebrew and reset my `SPARK_HOME` environment variable to `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0`. Now while executing pyspark, it gives a permission denied error. 


If I go into the earlier 1.5.2 installation directory and execute pyspark from there, it runs fine. But running pyspark from the 1.6.0 installation directory fails with this permission denied error.

`/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: Permission denied`

`/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0`

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked by doing 
`unset SPARK_HOME && pyspark` (credit to noli below)

Wanted to get the SparkContext running in Ipython, turned out to be quiet straightforward.

`unset SPARK_HOME
IPYTHON=1 pyspark`

Answer (score 29):

I ran into the same issue and the easiest fix is to set `$SPARK_HOME` to `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/<your_spark_version>/libexec/` instead.

You can also build from source directly and you can find the instructions [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html).

Basically just do

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/spark/`
cd spark
git checkout origin/branch-X.Y

build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

You'll need to set the `$SPARK_HOME` to the top level directory of the spark source code.

Comment: definitely a helpful alternative but I really need to get this working via homebrew

Comment: This does work via homebrew, which is what I have used. I am running on a MAC OSX High Sierra and changing the SPARK_HOME as suggested to /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/<your_spark_version>/libexec/  fixed the problem for me. I was having problems with `sparkR` as well and it fixed that problem too.

Comment: 2023 and still solving the issue.

Answer (score 4):

A ticket on the project page helped:

```
unset SPARK_HOME && spark-submit
```

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/48898#issuecomment-180633967

Answer (score 1):

For Pyspark 2.4.4 in MacOs add to .bash_profile:

```
# Pyspark
export SPARK_HOME='/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/'
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
#For python 3, You have to add the line below or you will get an 
# error
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[4]'
```

then reload with

```
source .bash_profile
```

and start pyspark with

```
pyspark
```

Do not unset SPARK_HOME or you will have the following error:

```
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/pyspark: line 24: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/pyspark: line 77: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec: /bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -2):

I also faced the same error like permission denied for starting `spark-shell`.
I changed file permissions. It worked fine for me.
Go to the parent directory of `spark-1.6.x` and do the following:

```
chmod 777 spark-1.6.x -R
```

This will change the permission of the file recursively.